# даты в строгой последовательности mysql

Tags: mysql, дата

Есть таблица. в ней поле даты.
в неё производятся записи каждый день. Подскажите как сделать запрос на проверку каждый ли день была запись? допустим есть ли данные за 4 дня?

Пример:

Есть записи для дат:

```
2017-06-06 ...
2017-06-07 ...
2017-06-09 ...
```

Как мне определить что 8 числа записи нет?

Comment: Задайте в `date` -> `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan нет такой возможности. принцип работы таблицы не позволяет. Да и что это даст. Всё равно что я буду сам дату записывать.

Comment: так если есть список дней то сделай выборку по этому массиву `SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE `date` IN ($date1,$date2,...)`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan дату я и так записываю сам. А так мысль. Спасибо.

Comment: если есть массив дат то сначала разбей на строку с запятыми. посмотри док для `WHERE IN`

Answer (score 0):

Приведу пример на MySQL.
Посоветую вам сделать соединение таблицы саму с собой.

Например, вы хотите посмотреть данные за прошедшую неделю и увидеть, сколько дней (и в какие дни) не были записи. Один из вариантов - `left join`:

```
select t1.date - interval 1 day
from test t1 left join test t2 on t1.date = t2.date + interval 1 day
where t2.date is null
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27f56b/3/0). Запрос выведет даты, если отсутствовало по 1 дню за раз.

В идеале вам для таких случаев иметь таблицу, где будут все дни и соединять с ней.

---

С помощью такого запроса увидите даты, между которыми были пропуски, но без вывода этих пустых дат:

```
select t.date,
  (select max(t1.date) from test t1 where t1.date < t.date) as last_date,
  t.date - (select max(t1.date) from test t1 where t1.date < t.date) as period
from test t
having period > 1
```